# onClick function firing on hover instead of click

Tags: javascript, html

It's a really simple thing -- I know but I keep getting results on getting it to fire on hover. I have an a tag that when I click it it would redirect me to html page within the project.

I have it like,

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="aboutRedirect()">
```

pageRedirect is simple JS:

```
<script>
    function aboutRedirect() {
        window.location.replace("/About");
    }
</script>
```

The reason why I am doing this instead of using just an href is because of Bootstrap. It's a dropdown menu and I have to have the data-toggle="dropdown" for it to work.

The question is how could I get rid of this hover feature that is happening. I tried to rebind the hover as a click with JQuery using this:

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function () {
$('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');});
```

But perhaps this is causing more problems that I am realizing?

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the question here?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the reason why the hover function is happening is not from this piece of code.
You Can Prevent On Hover For This Anchor Element By Just Adding This Piece Of Code To It.

`onmouseover="return false"`

`<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="aboutRedirect()" onmouseover="return false">`

Comment: Originally Bootstrap allows for hover so I changed it to a click. I don't know if this might be the issue but I added what you suggested and it didn't work... :/

Comment: Can You Post The Full Code And The Version Of The Plugins You're Using ?